# Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ prime such that $ord_p(a)=j$, $ord_p(b)=k$ and $ord_p(ab)=h$, then $a^{hk}\equiv1$ (mod $p$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ prime, such that:

- order of $a$ modulo $p$ is $j$.
- order of $b$ modulo $p$ is $k$.
- order of $ab$ modulo $p$ is $h$.

Then $a^{hk}\equiv1$ (mod $p$).

I am trying this problem, but still not got the result

Comment: It seems $j$ is not needed

Answer (score 2):

We have $b^k\equiv1$ and $(ab)^h\equiv1$, so $(ab)^{hk}\equiv1$, so $a^{hk}b^{hk}\equiv1$, so $a^{hk}(b^k)^h\equiv1$,

so $a^{hk}\equiv1\pmod p$.

Comment: You're right, I was trying to use that hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb Z_p$, which is cyclic, hence abelian, we have that $ab$ and $b^{-1}$ commute.  It follows that the order of their product divides the product of their orders.